# How to save certain parts of list as csv file in R?

Tags: r, list, csv, export-to-csv

I am sorry I have to ask this question but I am not a R-user. I would like to extract certain parts of my list ('alltracks'; see first 2 example data frames of my list, there are much more). I want to extract only those which are after 2015 (da shows the dates) and save them to csvs (I have learned that I cannot save the whole list to a csv since it is a list. I can save single parts of the list with

```
christian=alltracks$`201300262`
write.csv(christian,'christiantrack.csv')
```

However, I do not want to go through the whole list and do this for each step manually. Can anyone help me here? Many thanks

```
$`197900552`
    da  INDEX   SIZE    AREA    x   y   RADIUS  MEANV   STDV    MINV    MAXV    LONMAX  LATMAX  SSIn    SSIs    SSIu    SSIan
    1979112518  552     281     15.624  6.34    55.50   385.39  16.54   1.60    9.14    19.32   6.75    55.78   0.10833     34.35   58714.7     0.00856
    1979112600  552     278     15.151  12.86   56.73   559.89  11.90   3.03    6.99    16.56   11.81   56.63   0.06744     7.42    24727.2     0.00533
    1979112606  552     466     24.697  20.44   57.64   532.80  14.02   3.31    7.47    19.04   21.38   58.03   0.61935     131.99  63774.7     0.04896
    1979112612  552     1425    77.713  14.96   56.00   1212.80     12.54   3.62    6.34    18.78   6.19    55.50   1.41075     191.44  155061.6    0.11151
    1979112618  552     2177    116.476     16.27   56.46   1326.51     11.92   4.23    4.79    20.28   3.09    59.44   3.08396     362.51  223131.4    0.24377
    1979112700  552     2120    113.008     20.43   56.77   1265.43     11.48   3.94    4.60    20.66   18.56   58.59   6.18199     611.18  190836.4    0.48865
    1979112706  552     2085    110.357     22.01   58.02   1405.91     10.70   3.80    6.06    21.21   20.81   58.31   6.78306     937.33  155298.2    0.53616
    1979112712  552     1388    75.601  20.64   56.96   733.87  10.95   3.64    6.44    20.86   20.53   57.47   3.93638     544.97  109821.5    0.31115
    1979112718  552     551     29.797  22.26   57.34   704.24  11.12   3.52    7.22    19.03   20.53   56.91   0.43983     66.69   43677.6     0.03477
$`197900676`
    da  INDEX   SIZE    AREA    x   y   RADIUS  MEANV   STDV    MINV    MAXV    LONMAX  LATMAX  SSIn    SSIs    SSIu    SSIan
    1979120400  676     403     24.572  -22.31  52.16   841.18  19.48   0.81    17.79   21.26   -21.66  52.69   0.08568     43.98   147660.2    0.00677
    1979120406  676     618     34.581  -13.74  56.43   1014.93     19.37   1.01    11.97   22.22   -15.47  58.03   0.13904     68.46   204977.1    0.01099
    1979120412  676     1185    65.675  -8.16   54.72   954.63  16.89   3.78    7.79    22.18   -11.81  55.22   1.99375     378.46  291927.7    0.15759
    1979120418  676     1673    85.419  -3.50   57.59   926.42  17.29   3.85    3.04    25.11   -9.56   61.97   5.84061     1312.08     406945.6    0.46166
    1979120500  676     1774    84.716  4.71    61.22   791.20  15.25   6.23    3.21    28.63   -0.56   61.69   18.58224    4315.25     364391.8    1.46881
    1979120506  676     2261    104.739     10.14   62.69   1034.28     12.73   5.61    2.70    28.72   5.62    64.22   25.85656    3178.16     286410.5    2.04379
    1979120512  676     2598    119.657     13.57   64.40   1398.30     11.01   5.14    3.77    27.06   10.12   65.90   20.69610    2377.04     230466.7    1.63589
    1979120518  676     1165    49.241  14.87   65.16   699.40  11.85   5.55    3.90    23.39   6.75    66.46   6.24648     773.22  114765.8    0.49374
    1979120600  676     1240    53.699  13.33   64.19   961.31  10.43   5.05    2.88    22.67   8.72    65.62   4.60729     356.15  89704.6     0.36418
    1979120606  676     786     36.521  11.49   63.35   813.28  9.16    3.90    2.67    19.89   9.28    64.22   3.49895     113.00  37390.4     0.27657
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looping over the names of list elements.

```
lapply(names(alltracks), \(x) 
       write.csv(alltracks[[x]], sprintf('christian_track_%s.csv', x)))
```

**Note:** `"R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"`

Comment: this throws the error: 
`Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:5:26: unerwartete Eingabe
4: 
5: lapply(names(alltracks), \
                            ^
Traceback:`

Comment: @user17681970 Replace `\ ` by `function`. Your R version is too old.